# Professional way to handle program ownership in production

Tags: anchor, security, upgrade

Is there a preferred format to guarding program upgrade authority keypairs? In anchor, the `target` folder generates a keypair, which I assume has initial ownership.

If I want to switch over the ownership to a multisig from [squad](https://app.squads.so/squads) for example, how would management / upgrades happen in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally there's two ways this is handled:

- Upgrade authority is owned by a Multisig, meaning if you want to upgrade, the threshold specified in your multisig must be reached. The most popular solution for this you've already found, it's Squads.
- Revoking upgrade authority. Simply make your program non-upgradeable. This is the best case scenario, but not always an option depending on the specifics of your project.

Comment: That’s awesome. Do you know if squads has a tutorial on how to handle program upgrades and management? I’m not sure if there’s like a specific UI integration or not